# How to open a particular Chrome profile in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have two profiles for Chrome that I regularly use simultaneously, and I open up a lot of URLs with macros in Excel. I might be switching between the two Chrome windows, using one for miscellaneous stuff, and the other for opening all the links in Excel. When I open the URLs in Excel, I have it configured so that it will open only in Chrome, but it will always open the URL in my active Chrome window. I would like to be able to specify which profile it opens in. Is this possible?

The shortcut for my extra Chrome profile targets chrome like this:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
>   --profile-directory="Profile 1"

But I haven't found a way to specify this in the Shell command:

```
Dim CheckLast As Long
  CheckLast = Worksheets("Work").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

myStr = "http://" & Worksheets("Work").Cells(CheckLast, "C").Value
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe " & myStr
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, all I needed to do was add a space after the profile name. So if you ever want to open a link in excel in a specific profile on Chrome, here's how:

```
Dim CheckLast As Long
  CheckLast = Worksheets("Work").Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

myStr = "http://" & Worksheets("Work").Cells(CheckLast, "C").Value
Shell "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --profile-directory=""Profile 1"" " & myStr
```

Note that the two double quotation marks around the profile name ("Profile 1") are escaping the double quotes that are part of the string for calling the profile in Chrome.

This took me an inordinate amount of time to figure out. But now anyone who happens to google a similar issue will hopefully be able to find it.

Comment: Hi Sir,
My issue is a little different, i have to open a website and while submitting the form , i need to click submit button so that new tab(chrome) pops up and then i extract the data from that window and then closes it.
Is this possible in VBA selenium , because i'm finding many answers on JAVA & selenium.